# How to parse on a hash of symbols

Tags: ruby, parsing, hash, command-line-interface, symbols

I tried to `downcase` a parsed option to match only symbols in lower-case format because, when I match an uppercase OR mixed-case word my parser returns a nil value.

I don't want to have a hash like `[:ens, :ENS, :eNS, :enS ...]`:

```
opts.on("-i", "--instance [INSTANCE]", [:ens, :etu], "Selectionnez l'instance de Gitlab (etu, ens)") do |instance|
  # puts instance.inspect
  Options[:instance] = instance
end
```

Example:

```
./gitlabCollect -t my_token -k my_keyword -i ENS
```

will not work because the hash returned is:

```
{:token=>"my_token", :keyword=>"my_keyword", :instance=>nil}
```

Comment: So, what's the problem here?

Comment: You could remove the `[:ens, :etu]` from option definition and handle downcasing in the handler.

Comment: I let the two symbol an throw a error message when :instance => nil

Answer (score 0):

It seems you don't understand some things about symbols, they map to hashes based on their characters. `:sss != :Sss`. Try `:sss.hash` and `:Sss.hash` in irb/pry. You will see they map to two different numbers. If you need to be case indiscriminate, you can always convert to a string and `upcase` it.

```
symbol1 = :sss
symbol2 = :Sss

symbol1.to_s.upcase == symbol2.to_s.upcase #true
```

Comment: I tried to convert to string and downcase but `Options[:instance] = instance` return `nil` so convert does not work.